# pandas.DataFrame.asof() does not preserve dtype

Tags: pandas, numpy

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 2 ** 60
x = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int64)
y = np.array([N+1,N+2,N+3], dtype=np.int64)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y}).set_index('x')
df2 = df.asof(x+1)

print df.dtypes
print df2.dtypes
```

It produces:

```
y    int64
dtype: object
y    float64
dtype: object
```

Why does `df2` change the dtype from int64 to float64? How can I get it to be an int64 instead?

Note that simply calling `astype()` on the output of `asof()` is no good because the int64->float64->int64 round-trip loses precision:

```
print df['y'].astype(np.int64)
print df2['y'].astype(np.int64)
```

yields:

```
x
1    1152921504606846977
2    1152921504606846978
3    1152921504606846979
Name: y, dtype: int64
2    1152921504606846976
3    1152921504606846976
4    1152921504606846976
Name: y, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Does `df2.y` have any nans or infs? Their presence converts int columns to float.

Comment: My example produces the behavior I describe. It does not have nans or infs.

Comment: I came up with a solution of augmenting the DataFrame with an `np.arange()` array_indices, calling `asof()`, casting the floats back to ints, and then indexing the original int64 array with those array_indices. This works because the array_indices are small enough to survive the int->float->int round-trip without precision loss. Ugly but it'll do in the absence of better alternatives.